ExecutorService Callable thread mybatis insert 1M+ records throws CannotGetJdbcConnectionException Failed to obtain JDBC Connection
Below is Hikari connection settings
spring.datasource.hikari.connection-timeout=600000
spring.datasource.hikari.idle-timeout=300000
spring.datasource.hikari.max-lifetime=1800000
spring.datasource.hikari.maximum-pool-size=15
spring.datasource.hikari.minimum-idle=5

Below is the code, assign thread pool size as same as max connections, split 1M+ records list by 10k and inserting in to DB, using mybatis batch session
ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(15);
List<List<Employee>> listOfEmployees = new ArrayList<>(IntStream.range(0, totalEmployeeList.size()).boxed().collect(
Collectors.groupingBy(e -> e / 10000, Collectors.mapping(totalEmployeeList::get, Collectors.toList()))).values());
List<Callable<Void>> callables = listOfEmployees.stream().map(sublist ->
(Callable<Void>) () -> {
     dao.insertEmployees(sublist);
      return null;
    }).collect(Collectors.toList());
try {
   executorService.invokeAll(callables);
   executorService.shutdown();
} catch (InterruptedException e) {
  log.error("Exception in executing thread save", e);
}

Batch session code
Configuration:
@Bean(value = "batchSqlSession")
@Autowired
public SqlSessionTemplate batchSqlSession(SqlSessionFactory sqlSessionFactory) {       
   return new SqlSessionTemplate(sqlSessionFactory, ExecutorType.BATCH);
}

DAO:
public class EmployeeDAO {
private final SqlSessionTemplate sqlSessionTemplate;
private final EmployeeMapper employeeMapper;
    public EmployeeDAO (EmployeeMapper employeeMapper,
                     @Qualifier("batchSqlSession") SqlSessionTemplate sqlSessionTemplate) {
       this.sqlSessionTemplate = sqlSessionTemplate;
       this.employeeMapper=  sqlSessionTemplate.getMapper(EmployeeMapper.class);;
    }

@Transactional
public void insertEmployees(List<Employee> employeeList) {
        employeeList.stream().parallel().forEach(employee-> {
            try{
                employeeMapper.insertEmployees(employee);
            } catch(Exception ex){
                log.error("Exception - {} while inserting data {}",ex,employee.toString());
            }
        });
        sqlSessionTemplate.flushStatements();
        sqlSessionTemplate.clearCache();
    }

When i run this, i am getting

Caused by: org.apache.ibatis.exceptions.PersistenceException:
Error updating database.  Cause: org.springframework.jdbc.CannotGetJdbcConnectionException: Failed to
obtain JDBC Connection
The error may exist in mapper/EmployeeMapper.xml
The error may involve com.fmr.qrit.datasync.mapper.EmployeeMapper.insertEmployees
The error occurred while executing an update
Cause: org.springframework.jdbc.CannotGetJdbcConnectionException: Failed to obtain JDBC Connection at
org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.getConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:84)
at
org.mybatis.spring.transaction.SpringManagedTransaction.openConnection(SpringManagedTransaction.java:80)
at
org.mybatis.spring.transaction.SpringManagedTransaction.getConnection(SpringManagedTransaction.java:67)
at
org.apache.ibatis.executor.BaseExecutor.getConnection(BaseExecutor.java:348)
at
org.apache.ibatis.executor.BatchExecutor.doUpdate(BatchExecutor.java:70)
at
org.apache.ibatis.executor.BaseExecutor.update(BaseExecutor.java:117)
at
org.apache.ibatis.executor.CachingExecutor.update(CachingExecutor.java:76)
at
org.apache.ibatis.session.defaults.DefaultSqlSession.update(DefaultSqlSession.java:197)
... 22 more Caused by: java.sql.SQLTransientConnectionException:
HikariPool-1 - Connection is not available, request timed out after
30000ms (total=10, active=10, idle=0, waiting=6)  at
com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.createTimeoutException(HikariPool.java:686)
at
com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.getConnection(HikariPool.java:179)
at
com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.getConnection(HikariPool.java:144)
at
com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource.getConnection(HikariDataSource.java:127)
at
org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.lookup.AbstractRoutingDataSource.getConnection(AbstractRoutingDataSource.java:213)
at
org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.fetchConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:160)
at
org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.doGetConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:118)
at
org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.getConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:81)
... 29 more

I tried increasing connection pool size as 15 from 10 and then connection-timeout as 600000 from 300000, but same error

You really should not be doing that. This answer explains why.
As you use .parallel() (which I told you not to), it creates more threads via ForkJoinPool. This may be the direct cause of the exception.

I think the issue lies in the employeeList.stream().parallel().forEach() statement in your DAO method. Internally, it splits the list and executes concurrently, finally joining the results. This might have caused too many concurrent database connection requests, leading to the issue.
Parallel streams are ideally suitable for CPU-intensive operations, but they are not recommended for I/O-bound operations, such as database interactions.
Please try using a simple employeeList.stream().forEach operation instead

Thanks, i dont see that issue now after removing parallel and processing time is reduced by 50%

You already spawning up 15 threads in the executor service.
Then down again in transactional layer you are doing a parallel stream, which will use other idle threads.


@Transactional
public void insertEmployees(List<Employee> employeeList) {
        employeeList.stream().parallel().forEach(employee-> {
            // if connection is busy new connection is sought
            employeeMapper.insertEmployees(employee);
            
        sqlSessionTemplate.flushStatements();
        sqlSessionTemplate.clearCache();
    }



In the transactional block, if the current connection is busy, it will take a new connection from the pool.
Since the connection pool has 15 connections only and the number of threads are way more seeking connection is way more the parallel stream will break with the above exception.
The fix
would be to remove the parallel streaming on for each and lower down the
ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(15);

to some thing like
ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10);


Thanks, i dont see that issue now after removing parallel and processing time is reduced by 50%
